# How to print out the value of a variable in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

I have the following script:

```
i=1;
while [ $i -lt 51 ]
do
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
do script "php $i.php"
end tell' &
i=$[$i+1]
done
```

I am trying to open a terminal window that executes 1 of 50 php scripts. However, I cannot get the value of $1 to print correctly.  In fact, In each terminal its just blank. Each scripted is named 1.php to 50.php - how do I get the value of i to print properly to render the correct file name?

Note, I have been applescripting about an hour. Very open to suggestions to a better script. What I am trying to do is run 50 simultaneous PHP scripts in 50 separate windows simultaneously. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a quoting problem - change:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
do script "php $i.php"
end tell'
```

to:

```
osascript -e "tell app \"Terminal\"
do script \"php $i.php\"
end tell"
```